# Вычисление стажа работ из даты

Tags: javascript

**Вопрос**: В данном методе хотел вычислить возраст и стаж работы... С БД приходит дата начала работ и дата окончания(может прийти конкретная дата(если чел уволился), а может дата которую я запищу "по настоящее время" если чел еще работает), так вот вычисления возраста и стажа("по настоящее время") отрабатывают корректно, а вот если скажем с 10.10.2010 по 19.05.2019 по...то расчеты не верны...

**Код**:

```
getDateWorker(dateObject, dataEnd = null) {
  let today = new Date(); 
  // дата которую мы получаем с БД                                                                                
  let dateWorker = new Date(dateObject);  
  // находим разность текущего года и года из даты которую получили                                                                
  let year = today.getFullYear() - dateWorker.getFullYear();
  // находим разность текущего месяца и месяца из даты которую получили                                              
  let month = today.getMonth() - dateWorker.getMonth(); 
  // проверем: если месяц меньше 0 или (равен 0 и дата начала работ меньше даты окончания работ)
  if (month < 0 || (month === 0 && today.getDate() < dateWorker.getDate())){                          
     year--;                                                                                             
  }
   if(dataEnd && month < 0 || (month === 0 && today.getDate() < dateWorker.getDate())) {
 year--;
  }
  return year;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getDateWorker(dateObject, secondDate = null) {
   let dateEnd = new Date();
   if(secondDate) {
      if (secondDate > new Date().valueOf()) {
         dateEnd = new Date();
      } else {
         dateEnd = new Date(secondDate);
      }
   }
   let dateWorker = new Date(dateObject);
   let year = dateEnd.getFullYear() - dateWorker.getFullYear();
   let month = dateEnd.getMonth() - dateWorker.getMonth();
   if (month < 0 || (month === 0 && today.getDate() < dateWorker.getDate())){
      year--;
   }
```

Добавил доп. проверку(например бывает что с базы приходит дата окончания работ сотрудника как 31.01.9999, то при таких данных метод не работает...).

Comment: Уважаемый, зачем изобретать велосипед. Используйте готовые решения для работы с датой. Есть замечательная [библиотечка](https://momentjs.com/) ;-)

Comment: я хотел... но в компании сказали что есть какой-то недочет при работе с серверным временем...поэтому не используем данную библиотеку...Хотя в чем проблема была я не в курсе)

Answer (score 1):

```
getDateWorker(dateObject, dataEnd = null) {
  dataEnd = dataEnd || new Date(); 
  // дата которую мы получаем с БД                                                                                
  let dateWorker = new Date(dateObject);  
  // находим разность текущего года и года из даты которую получили                                                                
  let year = dataEnd.getFullYear() - dateWorker.getFullYear();
  // находим разность текущего месяца и месяца из даты которую получили                                              
  let month = dataEnd.getMonth() - dateWorker.getMonth(); 
  // проверем: если месяц меньше 0 или (равен 0 и дата начала работ меньше даты окончания работ)
  if (month < 0 || (month === 0 && today.getDate() < dateWorker.getDate())){                          
     year--;                                                                                             
  }
  return year;
}
```